# Julia - Concatenate list of matrices vertically

Tags: julia

I have a list of , say, `10` `10x5`-matrices and would like to concatenate all of them vertically to obtain a `100x5`-matrix

```
list_of_matrices = [randn(10, 5) for _ in 1:10]   # Each matrix is 10x5
output = vcat(list_of_matrices)                  # Would like output to be 100 x 5 dimensional
```

`vcat` and `cat` don't seem to work and produce a vector of matrices. What can I do?

Comment: Ah! foud it: `vcat(list_of_matrices...)`

Comment: Could you add that as an answer so that it's easier to find for others? You could also mention that this usage is shown in `vcat`'s docstring too, as the second example.

Comment: or `reduce(vcat, list_of_matrices)`

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods that work:

- `vcat(list_of_matrices...)`   can be found [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Base.vcat)
- `reduce(vcat, list_of_matrices)`